# scala.MatchError: 10 when running sbt command

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying run sbt command on my project.

But getting errors when it starts:

```
scala.MatchError: 10 (of class java.lang.String)
    at com.thoughtworks.sbtApiMappings.BootstrapApiMappings$$anonfun$globalSettings$1.apply(BootstrapApiMappings.scala:28)
    at com.thoughtworks.sbtApiMappings.BootstrapApiMappings$$anonfun$globalSettings$1.apply(BootstrapApiMappings.scala:27)
    at sbt.Init$Value$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Settings.scala:609)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$constant$1.apply(INode.scala:163)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$constant$1.apply(INode.scala:163)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

[error] scala.MatchError: 10 (of class java.lang.String)
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.

I used to run my project on another laptop, everything is fine. But when I move the project to my new laptop, I am gettings this error.

Don't know why this error is coming.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant lines from your sbt project file ?

Answer (score 2):

Solved,

sbt-api-mappings This SBT plugin seems incompatible with JAVA 10, I installed java 8, then sbt works.

Comment: maybe you just need to be using a newer version of sbt-api-mappings? https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/sbt-api-mappings/releases